# VS Code Jupyter does not render HTML as a default

Tags: visual-studio-code, rendering, jupyter-notebook

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Code for Windows 10 PC.

It does not render images or Pandas DataFrame as a default, and shows it as plain text.

The below image is the default setting.

[image: DataFrame as text]

Text/plain is the default option.
[image: This is default setting]

I have to change every single cell into HTML or an image.
[image: Manually changed into HTML]

It just shows it as plain text so I have to click the ... button on the left-hand side of the cell and change it into image/png or HTML for every single cell.

I searched 'notebook' or 'renderer' in the settings but could not find the appropriate option.

This phenomenon has happened from the last week even though I have not changed any settings.